# ASP .NET 5 site loses session after [FromBody] Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

we have an ASP.NET 5 Webserver with a Login, that sets Sessionvariables with HttpContext.Session.SetString. That are used later. This works perfectly fine.

Now we want an Entrypoint where you post all info to the Webserver that it needs (e.g. the Login Info) to return a Website. This works so far, but after we load any other Website in the Window, the Session is lost.

On client side we are using the CefSharp Browser to Post the data to the site ( like described here [Send POST data to URL with CefSharp C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449289/send-post-data-to-url-with-cefsharp-c-sharp) ).
Though I had to open the adress first and then post to it.
On Serverside we get the info like this.

```
        public IActionResult Entry(string id)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Entry");
            _logger.LogInformation("Session1: " + HttpContext.Session.Id);

            HttpContext.Session.SetString("test", "1");
            return new EmptyResult();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Entry(string id, [FromBody]SomeClass request)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("EntryPost");
            _logger.LogInformation("Session1: "+ HttpContext.Session.Id);
            process(request);
//(... set Session, create a Model and return a View)
```

Opening the Site enters the "Entry" and the Post afterwards enters "EntryPost". They already have different SessionIds, which isn't the end of the world, but as soon as we click a button in the BrowserView and it loads a new site the Session is lost as well.

I spend some time to properly send the Data per XML to the Server, this part works without a Problem. The Browser generally has no Problem saving Cookies from this Server, since the Website works properly through the Login-Page mentioned above.

We read a lot of problems with session losses through Redirects, so we erased them all, which at least showed the initial site without a Session loss, but not after the manual click to reload the site afterwards. We tried a lot of things, but we don't know why the session breaks.

If anyone has any ideas, please tell me.

Adding "simplified" version of the Browser code:

```
public class HTML : Form
{
    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
    private static bool _init;

    private void InitBrowser(string url)
    {
        if (!_init) {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings() { PersistSessionCookies = true }; // One of the things we tried
            _init = Cef.Initialize(settings); 
        }
        if (browser == null && _init == true)
        {
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url);
            this.Controls.Add(browser);
        }
    }

    public void setAddress(string address)
    {
        if (address == "") address = "about:blank";
        if (browser != null && browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
        {
            browser.Load(address);
        }
        else
        {
            InitBrowser(address);
        }
    }

    public override bool EntryPost(SomeClass request)
    {
        string gciXML = XMLTools.Serialize(gci);

        // setAddress("https://OurWebserver:44333/"); // Login Page, Website Works without problems
        InitPost("https://OurWebserver:44333/Home/Entry/id", gciXML);

        return true;
    }

    // Start Post functionality

    private Queue<PostParams> _postParam = new Queue<PostParams>();

    private class PostParams
    {
        public string url;
        public string postData;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// HTML Post. 
    /// Standard .NET Browser uses the same function name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url"></param>
    /// <param name="postDataBytes"></param>
    internal void Navigate(string url, byte[] postDataBytes)
    {
        IFrame frame = browser.GetMainFrame();
        IRequest request = frame.CreateRequest();

        request.Url = url;
        request.Method = "POST";

        request.InitializePostData();
        var element = request.PostData.CreatePostDataElement();
        element.Bytes = postDataBytes;
        request.PostData.AddElement(element);

        NameValueCollection headers = new NameValueCollection();
        headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
        request.Headers = headers;


        frame.LoadRequest(request);
        frame.GetTextAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
        {
            var html = taskHtml.Result;
            Console.WriteLine("HTML:" + html);
        });

        string script = string.Format("document.documentElement.outerHTML;");
        frame.EvaluateScriptAsync(script).ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            var response = x.Result;

            if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
            {
                var fullhtml = response.Result;
                Console.WriteLine("fullhtml:" + fullhtml.ToString());
            }
        }
        );
    }

    private void Browser_FrameLoadEnd_InitPost(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO Browser sometimes adds "/" to the url. This basicly runs into endless loop, but it works with the example
        if (browser.Address == _postParam.Peek().url)
        {
            browser.FrameLoadEnd -= Browser_FrameLoadEnd_InitPost;
            if (_postParam != null && _postParam.Count > 0)
            {
                PostParams postObject = _postParam.Dequeue();
                Navigate(postObject.url, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postObject.postData));
                
                // TODO repeat process if the queue isn't empty , works well for one Post Request for now
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.setAddress(_postParam.Peek().url);
        }
    }

    private void Browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged_InitPost(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
        {
            browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged -= Browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged_InitPost;

            this.setAddress(_postParam.Peek().url);
            browser.FrameLoadEnd += Browser_FrameLoadEnd_InitPost;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// puts the url and postData in a Queue and keeps it there until the Post is done
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pUrl"></param>
    /// <param name="pPostData"></param>
    internal void InitPost(string pUrl, string pPostData)
    {
        bool empty = _postParam.Count == 0;

        PostParams postObject = new PostParams() { url = pUrl, postData = pPostData };

        _postParam.Enqueue(postObject);

        if (empty)
        {
            // Decide what to do depending on the state of the browser
            if (browser == null) setAddress("");  // starts Init process
            if (!browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
            {
                browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += Browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged_InitPost;
            }
            else
            {
                Browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged_InitPost(null, null);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Explanation:

1. EntryPost is once called from outside on the Form.
2. InitPost decides what to do first, starts the init process on demand. You can give the browser a url on creating it - that's why I decided to combine it with the setAddress.
3. The PostUrl is loaded and we wait for the FrameLoadEnd Event.
4. When the Frame is done loading, the Post Request is sent.

The Navigate is copied from the linked stackoverflow page above. I think I added the Connection header. Iirc it sends a bunch of header info automatically.

Comment: `They already have different SessionIds, which isn't the end of the world` actually it is. It means the second action started a new session, possibly because it *is* a new session, started from a new tab or new browser instance. Anything you do at this point runs on a new session. CefSharp is a browser as far as any HTTP server is concerned

Comment: You have a CefSharp issue and yet there's no CefSharp code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right. I added the CefSharp Code. I thought, since the normal LoginPage works fine, there is no issue with the browser. But of course there is a bunch of other code, that can have issues. And with "it's not the end of the world" I meant practically, but I didn't know that it is a clue to the root of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems adding this in the Navigate function solved it:

```
request.Flags = UrlRequestFlags.AllowStoredCredentials;
```

or

```
request.Flags = request.Flags|UrlRequestFlags.AllowStoredCredentials;
```

Thanks to @PanagiotisKanavos for telling me that the issue is in the browser. I thought it's in the ASP.NET code.